# Lutris won't start Diablo Immortal

Tags: games, 22.04, lutris

I have a small problem with Lutris. I can install Battle.net and Diablo Immortal. But when I push the play button, it won’t start. I tried to repair the files, but it won’t help. Do you have any idea to solve the problem?

I tried to play this game on Ubuntu 20.04 and now with a fresh installation from Ubuntu 22.04. The installation from Battle.net with Lutris works fine. But when I installed Diablo Immortal, it won’t start. I can’t play it.

My system:

Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Graphics: AMD Readon rx 5700

Memory: 16 GiB

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

GNOME Version 42.2

Comment: I installed Lutris from Ubuntu Software. I can't found much information for that problem. Few posts I saw on reddit. I tried to install another wine version on lutris, but it does not work. Yesterday the game starts for 30 min. But then it crashed and nothing works more.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: You told us in your question that **it won't start** but now in comments you're telling us it crashed after 30 minutes. Now we are not only dealing with a lack of details, but inconsistent/incompatible ones. FWIW: I would not expect you to be able to play this game on Ubuntu. If you regularly intend to play games that only have Windows clients, I suggest that you set up your PC to dual boot. This is especially true if you intend to play new games, or online multiplayer games.

Comment: Running Windows software on Linux is like forcing a square peg into a round hole. Except sometimes the peg is an octagon, or it has spikes, or it is made of Swiss cheese. They are incompatible with each other and not designed to go together. Wine/Lutris is like an adapter that is not "one size fits all". So any time you want to install Windows software, you'll need to check with the Wine community about how to fit your particular software into a hole it wasn't designed to go in. Newer software lacks that community experimentation, and intricate software like MMOs may just not fit at all

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. When this problem can't be solve fast its ok. A second partition with Windows should be an option, but i don't like these. I don't must play the game, it was a try. :D

Answer (score 2):

Hi right click on Battlenet install, then click configure, check " show advanced option" go to runner option and put DXVK version to 1.10L and DXVK NVAPI 0.5.3. That's the only way to play it for me but I have an Nvidia GPU. And sorry if my English is not very well I'am French :)

Comment: This worked for me as well, I'm just curious how you found this solution?